# Difference in UseEffect and event listeners with React?

Tags: reactjs, addeventlistener, use-effect

So I'm trying to understand what's wrong with writing this event listener in React? I notice others wrap it in a useEffect hook and add a removeEventlistener, but I don't understand the point because it does the same thing as my code.

Here's my code

```
function App() {

 const hideMenu = () => {
   if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
   setIsOpen(false);
  }
 };

 window.addEventListener('resize', hideMenu);

}
```

What's the point of putting this code into a useEffect hook? Why can't I just use my code above and be fine?

Here's the same code put inside of a useEffect hook

```
      useEffect(() => {
        const hideMenu = () => {
          if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
            setIsOpen(false);
          }
        };

        window.addEventListener('resize', hideMenu);
      }, []);
```

Based off my site, both methods do the exact same thing, so how do I check in my console the purpose of doing useEffect vs the way I wrote it?

The whole point of my function is just to hide the mobile menu if the screen is larger than 768px.

Comment: In the version without the hook, you'll be adding multiple event listeners whenever your state changes. In the version with the hook, you only add the event listener once when the component mounts

Comment: would I need to add a return and remove the event listener as well?

Comment: Return from where? You should only add the event listener once (like you're doing with using useEffect), continuously removing it and adding a new one isn't very resourceful.

Comment: the answer below uses return, and that's what I've seen everyone mention online with event listeners and react

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 problems you can run into with your solution.

1. Every time a state variable changes or the component is re-rendered, it adds a new event listener to your window. If it is in a use effect with empty brackets, it will only run the first time the component is rendered, similar to a "ComponentDidMount".
2. If this were not your very top root component, and someone were to switch away from your screen, currently you aren't removing your event listener. This could be problematic in the future, or just be listening for useless information. When you remove the listener when it dismounts, it guarantees it is gone when it is unused, and if you were to go back, it would re-add the listener.

```
      useEffect(() => {
        const hideMenu = () => {
          if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
            setIsOpen(false);
          }
        };

        window.addEventListener('resize', hideMenu);

        return () => {
          window.removeEventListener('resize', hideMenu);
        }
      }, []);
```

Comment: ah so I console.log() my resize function and noticed that once I resize the screen past 768px, it continues to run even though the mobile menu has disappeared. How would I make it so that the function stops right after it reaches 768px and only runs again once I shrink back to mobile view and open the mobile menu again?

Comment: You don't need to remove the resize listener and add it if it is constantly being used. The unmount only happens when the component is not used anymore, but if it's navigation and it always is there even in mobile, then this is fine.

Comment: You will run into other scenarios this is more relevant for.

Comment: so right now if I am on desktop view and resize the screen to mobile, it triggers the function and console.logs like 40 times before I reach 768px. Then once I resize the screen back to desktop, it continues to console.log another 40 times, so basically the resize function runs whenever the screen resizes. Is that bad? I only need a function that hides my mobile dropdown menu once the screen is larger than 768px

Comment: ah I figured it out. I removed the dependency array and just added (window.innerWidth > 768 && isOpen) to my hideMenu function and it only logs the console value once

Comment: Event listeners are like live listeners, so as you are scrolling the window, the event listener function is getting called.

Comment: I notice tho everyone always say to add a dependency array. It seems for my example removing it fixes it, but why do people use it by default most of the time? Is it only working for my example because I am specifying whether or not my mobile menu is open or not ?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the purpose of the dependency array

Comment: For this example it might be working fine, but for others it will cause you massive headaches. Your app I assume is not getting re-rendered, but if it were getting re-rendered, every time yours would get called, and the dependency one would only get called the first render.

Comment: Make sure you mark this as the answer if it helped you so everyone knows you are good! :D

Comment: Your use effect is only adding the listener and removing it. The listener is called whenever resizes are happening.